# Efficient way of travelling with a lot of coins for coin machines

Tags: tips-and-tricks, hotels, money

What would be the most efficient way to handle traveling to a touristy place such as Disney, San Francisco,  Seaworld or Knott's Berry Farms where you know you will need many rolls of coins to go squish them in  coin machines? What I mean to say is should you travel with all your rolls of coins (which can get very heavy) or are you better off going to a local bank to get rolls of pennies and other such coins when you get to your location? Will hotels get rolls of coins for you and have them there when you check in? I have heard this is an option but I have never tried it before. Every time I have traveled I take my own rolls but the above mentioned places would require quite a few rolls of coins.

If I go to either Disneyland or Disney World you are looking at at least 100 to 150 coins that can be squished. The pennies would be anywhere from $.51 to $1.01 a piece (2 quarters to 4 quarters) and then you have to take into account the dime, nickel and quarter machines. The quarter machines would be at least $1.25 to $2.00 a piece per squished coins.  It could be an ENORMOUS amount of coins to bring with you.

Comment: One has to wonder how many of these you're doing on a trip to actually warrant carrying 100 pennies and $20 worth of quarters.

Comment: I don't think I have **ever** taken coins to any theme park or tourist place. I figure if they want my money they will make it easy for me to spend, not rely on me to go to extra trouble!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a couple of quarter dispensers. They can fit about 30 coins so that would make it easier for you. Pictured below is a dispenser with a spring but you can get plastic tubes for coins only, if you want and these hold maybe 40 coins.

[image]

Comment: I normally use Mini M & M containers. The are cheaper.

Comment: OK, no problem, I was merely giving a suggestion. BTW, consider accepting some answers on your other questions on this site. Perhaps then more people will answer this or any future questions you might have.

Comment: Back in the day when quarters were actually useful and film photography was still prevalent, 35mm film containers were quite useful for that purpose. But that was many, many moons ago...